# Import exisiting data into CoreData

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ipad, core-data

I have an existing database (SQL Server) which has several tables connected using primary/foreign key relationships. The database contains data and is used to populate a website.

I now want to use this data within a Mac/iOS application using CoreData and have created a data model and relationships as specified by Apple (and many others out there on the net). I have a simple service that pulls down the data from the remote system but am now struggling to see how I can use my CoreData model to persist this data on the device.

As CoreData is an object graph and not a database I do not know how I can preserve my primary/foreign key relationships as this is a CoreData implementation detail abstracted away from the developer. The data I have in my remote system relies on these already formed relationships to function correctly.

Does anybody out there know how to solve this issue or has come across it before? Or am I coming at this from the wrong angle?

Either way I need some way of replicating my remote data onto a Mac/iOS device.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys are relationships in Core Data. To transfer your database, you'll need to read through each row and make a new entity in Core Data. To recreate the relationships, you could store the old id data in there too, then query Core Data for an entity with that id, and create the relationship. If you only need to transfer it one time, you can delete the ids when the import is done.

Comment: This is sort of what I was thinking. Could not get my head around that my CoreData entity will have a relationship and a FK from the database. This then translates into my entity model class having a property for an NSManagedObject (CoreData relationship) and a property of type INT to hold the FK from the database. Hence why I wondered if this was the correct way to go, and had anybody else done anything like this (cant believe I'm the first!). ie A User has an Address so my User entity Model class would have properties for an Address entity (NSMangedObject) and an AddressId (int).

Comment: I think that your User entity would have a relationship which pointed to an Address entity. The Address entity would have an addressId property, originally from the database. You would fill the Core Data addresses first (so you can have something for the Users to point to). When you add a User, find the Address with the addressId coresponding to the database User. Then set the User relationship to the Address entity that you find.

Comment: If this method seems difficult, you could try directly inserting into the Core Data sqlite database. It's usually not recommended, but this tutorial tells you how. http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data

Comment: Thanks Nevan, much appreciated I will go with your first answer as it seems like the way to go and injecting directly into sqlite although can be done is bound to have me bug hunting well into the early hours :)